# Another thing can't get centered, AH

Tags: css, stylesheet, center, footer, html-lists

The center images in the footer are what I'm going for. They are the "certs" in my code!

I've tried different things from putting a div around it and using the margin:0 auto and trying to display the ul as a table and using the auto margins, for the heck of it tried inherit so that it would center align from the parent... I can't seem to figure it out! Even if I just put a simple left margin on it for test purposes it won't move.

Any help? :)

Comment: I think you need to remove some of the floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:0 auto` or `margin:auto` is always used with a fixed `width`.

So add `width:300px;margin:auto;` for `#certs`